# Firebase Phone Auth, How to retain user credentials?

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, mobile

I am trying to implement phone/SMS authentication using firebase. Once the user successfully verifies the code sent using SMS, the `firebase.auth().currentUser` 
is available for the duration user stays on the site. Once the user closes the browser and comes back, `currentUser` is null. I am using `LOCAL` persistence:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
      .then(() => firebase.auth()
          .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
          .then(result => {
            window.confirmationResult = result;
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error))
      )
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

and then

```
window.confirmationResult.confirm(code)
      .then(result => {
        this.user = result.user;
        console.log('Logged in');
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

How do I keep the user signed in and the `currentUser` available and only sign the user out explicitly?

It's not the best user experience if the user has to re-enter the phone number, wait for SMS and enter the code every time user visits my app.

Comment: Read the details about [Authentication State Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence). Make sure your browser has the capabilities needed to support LOCAL persistence.

Comment: It's too expensive to make it on every visit and not that extra security gain